# Outsourcing of object creation

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning how to outsource files in c++ with the QtCreator.
Why does the QSystrayIcon and the Window of note only appear when started directly in the main? If i comment "2" and insert "1" so that "3" is called, no systrayIcon occurs and only for a very small period the window appears, but gets immediately destroyed. But why? I have a instance of traymenu named mainmenu still alive in the main, how can it be destroyed?

main.cpp:

```
#include "traymenu.h"
#include "note.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    traymenu mainmenu;              //1

//    note w;                       //2
//    w.show();
//    QSystemTrayIcon tray;
//    tray.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("C:\\testicon.png")));
//    tray.setVisible(true);

    return a.exec();
}
```

traymenu.cpp:

```
#include "traymenu.h"
#include "note.h"
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>

traymenu::traymenu(QWidget *parent)
{

    note w;                        //3
    w.show();

    QSystemTrayIcon tray;
    tray.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("C:\\testicon.png")));
    tray.setVisible(true);
    tray.show();
}

traymenu::~traymenu()
{

}
```

note.cpp:

```
#include "note.h"
#include "ui_note.h"

note::note(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::note)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

note::~note()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an instance of `traymenu` but not an instance of `note`. `w` is a local variable, and it gets destroyed immediately after `traymenu::traymenu()` is executed. If you want the `note` instance to live until `main()` finishes, you have to make it a member variable of the `traymenu` class.

Comment: But how do I do this? In the corresponding headers traymenu.h and note.h the constructors are public, so why aren't they members?

Comment: At least I should see the trayicon appear.. my mainmenu is still existing, why should it be destroyed, it is saved in the main, isn't it?

Comment: @user2366975 `mainmenu` is still existing, but local variables defined in object's constructor do not continue to live with the object. Just like any other local variables, they are destroyed as soon as the constructor itself finishes. So after the line "//1" is executed, `w` and `tray` are already destroyed and their corresponding destructors `note::~note()` and `QSystemTrayIcon::~QSystemTrayIcon()` have been called.

Comment: @user2366975 "But how do I do this?" — Move `note w;` from the constructor to the class declaration (in traymenu.h).